# Difference in PCA with Scikit-Learn and SVD

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca, svd

I am working on a PCA example with Scikit-Learn and SVD in the following dataset. I thought I should get the same PCA components with both methods at the end however, what I find is that the signs get reversed. I followed different resources but correctly I assume. Did not quite understand why getting this sign reversal. Below is what I have done. `Xpca` and `Xsvd` should be same I thought.

Useful links [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca), [2](https://towardsdatascience.com/pca-and-svd-explained-with-numpy-5d13b0d2a4d8)

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data", header=None)
data.columns = ["V"+str(i) for i in range(1, len(data.columns)+1)]  # rename column names to be similar to R naming convention
data.V1 = data.V1.astype(str)
X = data.loc[:, "V2":]  # independent variables data
y = data.V1  # dependent variable data

# Using Scikit-Learn

from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

standardisedX = scale(X)
standardisedX = pd.DataFrame(standardisedX, index=X.index, columns=X.columns)

pca = PCA().fit(standardisedX)
Xpca = pd.DataFrame(pca.transform(standardisedX))

# Using SVD

U, S, V = np.linalg.svd(standardisedX, full_matrices=False, compute_uv=True)
Xsvd = pd.DataFrame(U.dot(np.diag(S)))
```

Comment: stats.exchange is the right place to ask this question.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/what-is-the-intuitive-relationship-between-svd-and-pca

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1805239/459718) is a concrete example explaining  why the sign reversal is happening. Like it says, there are many possible combinations of columns in U, and depending on the implementation the preference of selection is probably different.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it to this link, good details to know. Since it is a matrix with rank more than 1, there are many possibilities for U. I think I won't worry much just for the sign reversal in reality.